# Change background opacity of existing colored object

Tags: css, background-color

I have by JavaScript dynamically created objects with a background like `background-color: rgba(219, 219, 40, 1);`, with a content.

For some of them I want to edit the opacity, the 4'th argument of **rgba()** func. I can't add completely new CSS setting because color can change and I have to save it.

What can I do with CSS only?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible until there will be a property `background-opacity`. You can change the `opacity` but this will also influence the content.

Comment: show us how do you created your objects

Comment: @romph, they are created by a third-party library

Comment: @Alexey Can you simply add a `opacity: 0.4;` attribute?

Comment: @SujanSundareswaran, it makes the content transparent too

Comment: create a JS to change this value like you want

Answer (score 0):

You can save color like rgb(219, 219, 40) or HEX #DBDB28 and change opacity separately:

```css
.main{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(219, 219, 40);
  opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

</div>
```

Update:
Try to separate the content and the background in different divs

```css
.main{
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.background{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #DBDB28;
  opacity: .3;
}
.content{
  position: absolute;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #0099ff;
  opacity: .9;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="background">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
```

If that is not what you mean, show an example of the code

Comment: Nope, it affects the content

Comment: Objects are created by a third-party library. I can't restructure them without modifying the library. So I can operate with the existing result only

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, there is **not background-opacity** in CSS. Only thing you can do is to use rgba() every time, or you can create parent element with relative position and add child element with absolute position and change its opacity, it will not affect content:

```css
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.parent{
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
position:relative;
}

.parent .bg{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: #FF0000;
opacity: .5; /*Change opacity here dynamically*/
}
/*changing opacity of .bg will not affect .content*/
.parent .content{
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #0000FF;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Objects are created by a third-party library. I can't restructure them without modifying the library. So I can operate with the existing result only

Comment: In CSS you do not have other alternatives, the only way is using JS. You can get RGBA() color of the element change the opacity and then change CSS of element again.

Comment: Ok. Probably this question will stay open until we have something like **background-opacity**